# Symmetric difference

Tags: code-golf

Surprised that we don't have a symmetric difference challenge yet.

Given two lists only containing positive integers, return all items among these two lists that aren't contained in both of the lists.

### Rules

From the set definition:

> A set is a collection of definite distinct items.

- So you can assume the items in the input lists are always unique.
- You can also take input as a set if your language supports it.

### Test cases

[Here](https://tio.run/##bY2xCsMgFAD39xVv9JFnIG2nUAr6FYI4pEWKEE1RIRTy7zZZSofecNPB@TxP6Sl9eeTwqq1BeUehWBPKG@CONbhtaPAqUTGmpeIcSi1j9PHuszCMmhxg1/2W@n@pyPUAcQpJWPc9hGVcc6heHGs78InPju1uvjiivrUP) is a sample program that generates the test cases.

```
[1,2,3],[2,3,4] -> [1,4]
```

Comment: C++ has a builtin but it doesn't work. I'm going to go ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œ^
```

It's a two-byte dyadic atom (i.e. a built-in).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Lj///9HG@oY6RjH/o8GkjomsQA)**

Answer (score 12):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/78410)

```apl
∪~∩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHqrpHHSv/pz1qm/Cot@9RV/Oh9caP2iY@6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/GyoYKRgrpIFJEwA)

#### How it works

```apl
∪~∩  ⍝ Input: two sets as vectors
∪    ⍝ Set union
 ~   ⍝ Set minus
  ∩  ⍝ Set intersection
```

---

The rest is just for fun.

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/78410)

```apl
~∪~⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@5Rx6q6R70r/qc9apvwqLfvUVfzofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/xsqGCkYK6SBSRMuGM9EwVLBCAA)

```apl
~∪~⍨
~     ⍝ Set difference (a~b)
 ∪    ⍝ Set union
  ~⍨  ⍝ Set difference reversed (b~a)
```

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/78410)

```apl
~⍨∪⍨~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@5R74pHHauAZN3/tEdtEx719j3qaj603vhR28RHfVODg5yBZIiHZ/B/QwUjBWOFNDBpwgXjmShYKhgBAA)

This one is palindromic!

#### How it works

```apl
~⍨∪⍨~
~⍨     ⍝ Set difference reversed (b~a)
  ∪⍨   ⍝ Set union reversed
    ~  ⍝ Set difference (a~b)
```

Comment: The only symmetric answer so far.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 11 bytes

```python
set.__xor__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzvzi1RC8@viK/KD7@f0FRZl6JRppGtaGOkY5xrU41kNQxqdXU/A8A)

For built-in `set` objects, `a^b` computes symmetrical set difference. `__xor__` is the magic name for that operator, and it is shorter than `lambda a,b:a^b`.

Also works in [Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzvzi1RC8@viK/KD7@f0FRZl6JRppGtaGOkY5xrU41kNQxqdXU/A8A).

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Bubbler!

```
-.,-.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/dfV0dPXq/mtyKXClJmfkKxgqGCkYK6SBSZP/AA)

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 11 bytes

```
{(x^y),y^x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqMirlJTpzKuovZ/WrShgpGCsTUQK5jE/gcA)

Comment: Shouldn't `-.,-.~` work in J?

Comment: @Bubbler Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @user41805*

```bash
rs 0 1|sort|uniq -u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6hYwUDBsKY4v6ikpjQvs1BBt/T/f0MFIwVjLiBWMAEA)

Comment: `rs 0 1` is shorter than tr

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
Join@##~Complement~Intersection@##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773ys/M89BWbnOOT@3ICc1NzWvpM4zryS1qDg1uSQzHySl9j@gKDOvRMEhPbraUMdIx7hWpxpI6pjUxv7/DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
«¹²ÃK
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0OpDOw9tOtzs/f9/tKGOkY5xLFc0kNQxiQUA)**

#### How?

```
«     - merge the two input lists   -> a+b
 ¹    - push 1st input list            a,a+b
  ²   - push 2nd input list            b,a,a+b
   Ã  - intersection                   b&a,a+b
    K - discard                        (a+b)-(b&a)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>98</s> 96 bytes

```c
*d;f(a,b,c)int*a,*b,*c;{for(;*c=*a++;c+=!(*d=-*d))for(d=b;*d&&*d-*c;d++);for(;*c=*b++;c+=*c>0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dCsIwDIXvfYo6UJq0g/pzF@qLiBdp6uZAp6jgYPjq1naCNzmEnHPySd2KpISRGs02WIGufyJbDBaFxuZ614TikY0hMX6uMfoaI0C5RB8I43KJsc7maAzQPxB@AZSdA3qnC3e9hjGXK96vnDvY8BOZhFrNkEeAP8dUVWAGL4QD3e55aXS1iKqyOORnuXdWchMxja9Tdz7qh3A/uSrLkNG4UL3TSq3VRrlZmVvlPtKcuX2k@vUF)

*-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat*

Input is in two 0-terminated arrays `a` and `b`, output as a 0-terminated array into preallocated buffer `c`.

Comment: Looks like it would be break-even to use a standard `f(int*a,int*b,int*c){` instead of K&R.  The repeated `a,*b,*c;` part is 8 bytes, same as 2x `int*`.  No saving but nicer to read :/

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a-b|b-a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6UTepJkk3sfZ/gUJatEK0oY6RjnGsjkI0kNIxiVWI/Q8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```r
function(x,y,`-`=setdiff)union(x-y,y-x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqdSJ0E3wbY4tSQlMy1NszQPLKpbqVOpW6H5P03D0MpYx8jKRPM/AA)

Thanks to [user Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)'s [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203364/symmetric-difference/203484#comment484073_203484).

The original was the following.

```r
function(x,y){s=setdiff;union(s(x,y),s(y,x))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P600L7kkMz9Po0KnUrO62LY4tSQlMy3NujQPJFgMFtYp1qjUqdDUrP3/HwA)

Straightforward, definition coded in R.

Note: the following function is also 45 bytes. I thought that to define `s=setdiff` first would save a few bytes but as it turns out the function will need a semi-colon instruction separator and to be between braces. For the same byte count a no-tricks function is more natural.

```r
function(x,y)union(setdiff(x,y),setdiff(y,x))
```

Comment: You can still avoid those braces by aliasing `setdiff` inside function definition. And in this particular case you can save even more bytes, by aliasing it not as a variable, but as an operator! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqdSJ0E3wbY4tSQlMy1NszQPLKpbqVOpW6H5P03D0MpYx8jKRPM/AA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 25 bytes

```
func[a b][difference a b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OlEhKTY6JTMtLbUoNS85VQHE/19QlJ@UqpCmEG2oYKRgHBsNJBRMYv8DAA)

Comment: Sounds like `difference` (10 bytes) should be a valid solution...?

Comment: @Bubbler I don't know - it would be just a word - neither a program nor a function.

Comment: @Bubbler [Something like this?](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy1VQlJlX8j8lMy0ttSg1Lzn1f7ShgpGCcWw0kFAwif0PAA)

Comment: Yeah. I think it is valid under CGCC rule because the word itself is reusable (even if you can't easily assign it to a different name).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
«©ʒ®s¢
```

How does it work?

```
« merge lists
 © store in the global register
  ʒ keep only items which
   ®s¢ the number of times which they appear in the merged list is truthy, which is only 1 in 05AB1E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0OpDK09NOrSu@NCi//@jDXWMdIxjuaKBpI5JLAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
Ｉ⁺⁻θη⁻ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyCntFjDNzMPSBbqKGRo6ihAOBk6CoWaQGD9/390tKGOkY5xrE40kNQxiY39r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        First input
    η       Second input
  ⁻         Remove matching elements
      η     Second input
       θ    First input
     ⁻      Remove matching elements
 ⁺          Concatenate
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`, where \$a\$ and \$b\$ are Sets. Returns a list.

JS has very few set built-ins, so this a bit verbose.

```javascript
a=>b=>[...a,...b].filter(x=>a.has(x)^b.has(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RchBCsMgEEDRq7icATvQplu9RJeSwpiMrUW0RGlze5NCIZvP5734w3Va4rudcpmlB9PZWG@sIyLWe/xIIaYmC6zGMj25wop3/x/sU8m1JKFUHhAgy1fdpIE7a3XRahgRD/uBVtfdsG8)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
X~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6Lu//9oQx0jHeNYrmggqWMSCwA)

#### Explanation

Built-in. Implicit inputs, implicit output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 7 bytes

```julia
symdiff
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v7gyNyUzLe1/QVFmXokGlKcRbaijYKSjYByroxANonUUTGI1Nf8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
«Ð¢Ï
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0OrDEw4tOtz//3@0oY6RjnEsVzSQ1DGJBQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
      #  i.e. inputs: [1,2,3] and [2,3,4]
«     # Merge the two (implicit) input-lists together
      #  STACK: [[2,3,4,1,2,3]]
 Ð    # Triplicate this merged list
      #  STACK: [[2,3,4,1,2,3],[2,3,4,1,2,3],[2,3,4,1,2,3]]
  ¢   # Count all occurrences of the values in the list
      #  STACK: [[2,3,4,1,2,3],[2,2,1,1,2,2]]
   Ï  # Only leave the values at the truthy (count = 1) indices
      #  STACK: [[4,1]]
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
x%y=filter(`notElem`y)x
x#y=x%y++y%x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0K10jYtM6cktUgjIS@/xDUnNTehUrOCq0K50hYop61dqVrxPy1NwVZBQ1mTKzcxMw/ILCjKzCtRUFEAikcb6hjpGMcqRANJHZPY/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 38 bytes

```
procedure f(a,b)
return a++b--a**b
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw7DoAgEAV7ToHdri6Fn9sYC5AloRDMihpPr8bKV80kkxfnnO57lTyz34V1AEsOlXDZJWnbNM4YW9dOcfK/bLExASr9jg@WS58SC0MVYOMCY0sd9RPSJy/SMCHi9/EA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```
f={a,b->a-b+(b-a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/zbY6USdJ1y5RN0lbI0k3UbP2f0FRZl6JQppGtKGOkY5xrE40kNQxidX8DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$a+$b|group|? c* -eq 1|% n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJUyVRWyWpJr0ov7Sgxl4hWUtBN7VQwbBGVSFP6////4Y6RjrG/4FYxwQA)

unrolled:

```powershell
param($a,$b)
$a+$b|group|where count -eq 1|% name
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
-sQ@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X7c40MHt//9qQx0jHeNanWogqWNSCwA)

```
 sQ   sum inputs (union since inputs are sets)
-     minus
   @F intersection of inputs
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

```perl
sub u{map$k{$_}++,@_;grep$k{$_}==1,keys%k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEmhtDo3sUAlu1olvlZbW8ch3jq9KBXKt7U11MlOrSxWza79X1BanOGQqOPgVltdnFipkJZfpFDqkPjfUMFIwZgLiBVM/uUXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNPivm5gDAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, ≥ 4 B

The symmetric difference operator denoted `><` is defined by ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” as part of the programming language.

```pascal
A><B        { where `A` and `B` are assignment-compatible `set` expressions }
```

In “Standard Pascal”, defined by ISO standard 7185, you will need to resort to basic operators:

```pascal
(A−B)+(B−A)
```

[RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Pascal) │ [FreePascal Compiler wiki](https://wiki.FreePascal.org/symmetric_difference) │ [Pascal programming WikiBook](https://en.WikiBooks.org/wiki/Pascal_Programming/Sets#Operations)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 49 bytes (no built-in set operations)

```python
lambda s,t:[a for a in s+t if(a in s)*(a in t)<1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3DXMSc5NSEhWKdUqsohMV0vKLFBIVMvMUirVLFDLTNCBsTS0Io0TTxjAWqnFyui2SVo1i3RLNGo0S3WJNrgxUiZoSTV2NEjWgREFRZl6JRppGtKGOkY5xrE60sY6JjmmsJkwmXaM4tQQmq6kD5sCUwNRk4FMDcdqCBRAaAA)

takes two lists as input, returns symmetric difference of those lists
(concatenation without elements that appear in both lists)

### Python, 22 bytes

```
lambda s,t:(s-t)|(t-s)
```

```
lambda s,t:(s|t)-(t&s)
```

build symmetric difference as union of differences / union without intersection

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sets.extras`, 14 bytes

```
symmetric-diff
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpSrJdaUVKUWKxQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVVrWCoYKRgrFCrUA2mTRRq/xdX5uamlhRlJuumZKal/df7DwA)

---

**No builtin:**

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 25 bytes

```
[ 2dup ∪ -rot ∩ ∖ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6KQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXmpeZnJ@SqmDNxVWtYKhgpGCsUKtQDaZNFGr/RysYpZQWKDzqWKWgW5RfAmSsBOJpCrH/kxNzchT0/gMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 11 bytes

This is a direct port of [daniero's Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203426/11261); give them an upvote. Mostly I wanted to post it because it looks like a bunch of emoticons.

```ruby
:|%[:-,~:-]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWq61qVKOtdHXqrHRjISJbChTcoqMNdYx0jGN1ooGkjkksVGrBAggNAA)

### Explanation

```
:| % [:-, ~:-]
:| % [  ,    ]  # Union of...
      :-        #   difference (a-b) and
          ~:-   #   reversed-argument difference (b-a)
```